# How to decode this url, its pretty complicated

Tags: url, base64, encryption

I am in a jam here, I am trying to decode this url,

http://www.fastpasstv.ms/redirect/?url=3uXn46ChlNzr7Z%2Fp3MrqycripNTi4JXVyp3h3N2r3sqo1N4%3D

This takes you to the

http://www.vidxden.com/ce8mfl8kd6oy

I have run base64 decoding for "3uXn46ChlNzr7Z%2Fp3MrqycripNTi4JXVyp3h3N2r3sqo1N4%3D" and it comes as jibberish. 
I am an imacros coder and need to decode this string for my client, Please help me out in this jam.

Regards
Ram

Comment: are you sure this is an encoded url, and not an internal arbitrary key?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't decode to that URL, it decodes to a URL that when downloaded will redirect to your target:

```
$ python3 -c "import urllib.parse; print(urllib.parse.unquote('http://www.fastpasstv.ms/redirect/?url=3uXn46ChlNzr7Z/p3MrqycripNTi4JXVyp3h3N2r3sqo1N4='))"
http://www.fastpasstv.ms/redirect/?url=3uXn46ChlNzr7Z/p3MrqycripNTi4JXVyp3h3N2r3sqo1N4=

$ curl -sS http://www.fastpasstv.ms/redirect/?url=3uXn46ChlNzr7Z/p3MrqycripNTi4JXVyp3h3N2r3sqo1N4= -D /dev/tty
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.0.11
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://www.vidxden.com/ce8mfl8kd6oy
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 05 Jun 2012 22:54:31 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Note the 302 status and the Location header

Comment: Yea, Thanks for your help, sorry my reputation is not enough to vote up

Answer (score 1):

I was curious, and did some tries.

- feeding http://www.insidepro.com/hashes.php?lang=eng with http://www.vidxden.com/ce8mfl8kd6oy or www.vidxden.com/ce8mfl8kd6oy does not result in the url to interpret
- using http://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/ on 3uXn46ChlNzr7Z/p3MrqycripNTi4JXVyp3h3N2r3sqo1N4= or 3uXn46ChlNzr7Z%2Fp3MrqycripNTi4JXVyp3h3N2r3sqo1N4%3D does not give any result
- However: 3uXn46ChlNzr7Z seems to be repeatedly used by fastpasstv (google for it). And the rest (p3MrqycripNTi4JXVyp3h3N2r3sqo1N4) is said to possibly be a MD5 Hash by Hash ID.

You will not easily decrypt the MD5 hash...

So, it seems you are out of luck for decrypting this. Just follow the redirect...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will have to follow only.